# SQL Division with zero must not be done and must not affect other calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table valued function in SQL Server that calculates any mathematical operation between 2 numbers. Division with zero must return a warning and the computation must not be done. I noticed that by system there is a message "Divide by zero error encountered" but it affects the other calculations (addition, subtraction, multiplication).

So here is my code with the version of NULL as result of division with error so it does not mess up.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION get_math
(
    @p1 decimal, 
    @p2 decimal
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @p1 + @p2 AS 'add',
     @p1 - @p2 AS 'substract',
     @p1 * @p2 AS 'multiply',
    
     CASE 
        WHEN @p2 = 0
        THEN null
        ELSE  CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(@p1/@p2))
    END AS 'divide'     
)
GO
```

[image: results from the code for p1 = 15 and p2= 5]

I want when the second parameter is zero, only the division to be stopped and show a warning message in the 4th column (divide). The other calculations should be done without any problem.
Can someone offer me an idea?

Comment: In which column will you return an error? And your code works as is... you need to provide a [mre] which shows it not working. Please show what your desired results are for a 0 input.

Comment: You can't, because that would be mixing data types, every column returned in the table must be consistent, so if column 4 returns a decimal you can't in some cases return a string. You need a column 5 for warnings.

Comment: The underscore was a typo. I fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just return zero or some special value for the divide value to indicate p2 is zero?

Comment: @Stu this is the request of the exercise. I know it does not make much sense but I had to do exactly what was asked. Thank you for your notice.

Comment: Ah, okay. For I would have argued that returning NULL for the division result already says that the division does not lead to a valid result :-) Returning NULL is a warning hence. (But it doesn't explain what exactly went wrong; you'd also get NULL when one of the operands is NULL:)

Comment: `CONVERT(decimal(10,2) @p1) / NULLIF(@p2, 0)` is the quickest way to get a null for division-by-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it exactly as you ask for, because that would be mixing data types, every column returned in the table must be consistent, so if column 4 returns a decimal you can't in some cases, instead, return a string. You need a column 5 for warnings.

```
    DECLARE @p1 decimal = 0, @p2 decimal = 0;

    SELECT
        @p1 + @p2 add

        , @p1 - @p2 substract
        
        , @p1 * @p2 multiply
    
        , CASE 
            WHEN @p2 = 0
            THEN null
            ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(@p1/@p2))
        END AS divide

        , CASE 
            WHEN @p2 = 0
            THEN 'Cannot divide by zero'
            ELSE null
        END AS divideError
```

Comment: That would be an a good alternative. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can convert the decimal result to a varchar (although I would rather keep them separate just like you did)

Comment: @SalmanA true... but thats not a solution I would be happy with.